# changing global time to local timezone on cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am a newbie at Firebase cloud functions. I am making so simple function and I need to get the current time to convert my timezone. But the Firebase cloud function's console gives me TypeError: currentTime.getDate(...).toLocaleDateString is not a function message.

Here is my code:

```
  exports.simdikizamanim = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/name').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
// it works
const currentTime =  new Date()
const   currentDate = currentTime.getDate().toLocaleDateString('tr-TR', { timeZone: 'Europe/istanbul' });
const    currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth().toLocaleDateString('tr-TR', { timeZone: 'Europe/istanbul' });
const   currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear().toLocaleDateString('tr-TR', { timeZone: 'Europe/istanbul' });
  
const   currenthours = currentTime.getHours().toLocaleDateString('tr-TR', { timeZone: 'Europe/istanbul' });
const   currentminutes = currentTime.getMinutes().toLocaleTimeString('tr-TR', { timeZone: 'Europe/istanbul' });
const   currentsecond = currentTime.getMinutes().toLocaleTimeString('tr-TR', { timeZone: 'Europe/istanbul' });

const dateFormat = currentDate + " " + currentMonth + "" + currentYear + "T" + currenthours + ":" + currentminutes + ":" + currentsecond + "Z"

    console.log(dateFormat + " sad");

  });
```

I should write dateFormat to my cloud function's console. TypeError: currentTime.getDate(...).toLocaleDateString is not a function. It gives me message. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) for the getDate() method that you're using on a Date object.  It says:

> Return value
>
> An integer, between 1 and 31, representing the day of the month for the given date according to local time. Returns NaN if the date is invalid.

So it returns a number.  You can't call any methods on a number.  This is what the error message is trying to tell you - there is no function `toLocaleDateString` on a number.

`toLocaleDateString` is a method on a Date object, which you already have in the `currentTime` variable.  So just call it like this with the arguments you want:

```
const currentDate currentTime.toLocaleDateString(...)
```

Your other calls to `toLocaleDateString` are going to have the exact same problem since they are also trying to call a method on a number.